# GCC: Why is const data filled inside my function and not at the beginning?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, constants

I want to benchmark the number of cycles used by different machine instructions on my system (for this example it is ARM Cortex-M4). So i use a macro, which repeats the target instruction a number of times and before and after this, i read the cycle counter of my controller. In the asm-dump, i see that at some position the const data (address of my cycle-counter register) is filled in (position 8003140 to 8003150, marked with ">"):

```
    08002d58 <testThis>:
    8002d58:    48fa        ldr r0, [pc, #1000] ; (8003144 <testThis+0x3ec>)
    8002d5a:    49fb        ldr r1, [pc, #1004] ; (8003148 <testThis+0x3f0>)
    8002d5c:    4bfb        ldr r3, [pc, #1004] ; (800314c <testThis+0x3f4>)
    8002d5e:    4afc        ldr r2, [pc, #1008] ; (8003150 <testThis+0x3f8>)
    8002d60:    6800        ldr r0, [r0, #0]
    8002d62:    6008        str r0, [r1, #0]
    8002d64:    681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
    8002d66:    6812        ldr r2, [r2, #0]
    8002d68:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    8002d6c:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    ..
    8003138:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    800313c:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    > 8003140:  e008        b.n 8003154 <testThis+0x3fc>
    > 8003142:  bf00        nop
    > 8003144:  e0001004    .word   0xe0001004
    > 8003148:  20000598    .word   0x20000598
    > 800314c:  20000594    .word   0x20000594
    > 8003150:  200002e4    .word   0x200002e4
    8003154:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    8003158:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    ..
    8003b84:    fa82 f183   qadd    r1, r3, r2
    8003b88:    fa82 f383   qadd    r3, r3, r2
    8003b8c:    4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (8003b9c <testThis+0xe44>)
    8003b8e:    4904        ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; (8003ba0 <testThis+0xe48>)
    8003b90:    6003        str r3, [r0, #0]
    8003b92:    4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (8003ba4 <testThis+0xe4c>)
    8003b94:    680a        ldr r2, [r1, #0]
    8003b96:    601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
    8003b98:    4770        bx  lr
    8003b9a:    bf00        nop
    8003b9c:    2000058c    .word   0x2000058c
    8003ba0:    e0001004    .word   0xe0001004
    8003ba4:    20000338    .word   0x20000338
```

Why is this not filled in at the beginning?
Am i able to control this?

GCC version:

> gcc version 4.8.3 20140228 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 208322]

C-Code:

```
    #define READCYCCNT() *((volatile unsigned int *)0xE0001004)

    uint32_t cyc_begin, cyc_end;
    int c, a, b;
    void testThis(void *obj)
    {
        cyc_begin = READCYCCNT();
        REP(9,0,0, c, __QADD, a, b);
        cyc_end = READCYCCNT();
    }
```

The REP-macro is a bit lengthy. It just adds 900 calls to

```
    c = __QADD(a,b)
```

Compiler-call:

```
    arm-atollic-eabi-gcc -c -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -std=gnu90 -DDEBUG=1 -I../Inc -I../CoreSupport -I../DeviceSupport -Ofast -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -Wall -o Application\Main.o ..\Application\Main.c
```

Comment: You have forgotten to post the C source...

Comment: And also give the compilation command. So please edit your question to improve it! BTW, you might use `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O`

Comment: And also please tell us the addresses of the instructions that you are worried about.

Comment: It does not matter at all in which order the code / data is in the memory.

Comment: In this case, as i want to benchmark the execution time, i would like not benchmark the branch (at 8003140), which is now generated inside the execution.

Comment: It is "filled in at the beginning" in that those literals are loaded by the first few instructions - the literal pool would normally be placed after the function, but that would be too far away for the 16-bit ldr/str encodings to address, so it just gets dumped where it is and jumped over. Different optimisation options may change the instruction selection to allow different literal pool placement. Also, you know [the instruction timings are already documented](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100166_0001_00_en/ric1417175924567.html)?

Comment: That constant data seems like instructions in wrong endianness.

Comment: I am aware of the already documented timings, but in an actual scenario also flash latencies have to be regarded. In this case, I wanted to measure something, of which I know the execution time, to ensure my measurement is correct.

Comment: If all it costs is one `b.n` instruction in 900 repetitions, I would say: ignore it.

Comment: @auselen: They are not instructions at all, they are addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler have generated your code using ldr instructions with addressing relative to PC. Those instructions have only 5 bits to store the relative address, so they can only access data within range 0-124 words from the current program counter position. This is why the compiler have placed your data in the middle of the code. Here's the [quick reference card](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0006e/QRC0006_UAL16.pdf) for thumb instructions.

There are several ways to avoid this. You could replace the macro by a hand-written assembly which uses different addressing mode. You could replace variables by constants and avoid addressing altogether. You could reduce the number of times your macro is called. You could remove the -mthumb flag to generate 32-bit instructions which have more bits for addressing. It really depends on what you want to evaluate with your test.

Comment: Cortex-M4 only supports the Thumb instruction set, so dropping -mthumb wouldn't be a solution.